# Printing 'True' index/es after comparing numpy arrays with numpy.logical_and(...)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Is there a more elegant way to return the index of a `True` value when comparing arrays using `numpy.logical_and(...)` than just looping through the boolean result vector and printing/saving the index?

Currently I have something like:

```
array1 = numpy.array([1,2,3])
array2 = numpy.array([0.5,1.2,2])
comp = numpy.logical_and(numpy.logical_and(array1 != 0, array2 != 0), array1 > (3*array2))
if True in comp:
    # basically just loop and find True/s.
```

Would prefer something that just returns the locations that have true values so I can more easily and access them faster in the original ararys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `numpy.where()`, more particularly here `numpy.where(comp)[0]`

As a remark, you MCVE is not very well chosen, since comp does not contain True.
If instead I use

```
comp = numpy.logical_and(numpy.logical_and(array1 != 0, array2 != 0), array1 > (0.6+array2))
```

Then I get

```
>>>comp
array([False,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
>>> np.where(comp)
(array([1, 2]),)
>>> np.where(comp)[0]
array([1, 2])
```